# Raspberry Pi 2 and DS1621

Tags: pi-2, sensor, temperature

I am connecting temperature sensor, DS1621 with Raspberry Pi 2.
Pin 5,6,7 and 8 of DS1621 is connected to 3.3V and pin 1 is connected to SDA, pin2 is connected to Clock and pin 4 is connected to GND.

However when i try to see result of I2C bus, no device is found.

Troubleshoooting step followed:
i) Installed moduels
ii) Installed i2c-tools
iii) dtparam=i2c1=on, dtparam=i2c_arm=on added in config.txt

Any hint to test this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A photo of your connections would be useful.  How do you "try to see result of I2C bus"?

Comment: @joan: Please find below detection process of i2c.

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


How can i upload image here?

Comment: It it is probably better to edit your question to add the i2cdetect output.  Also when you edit the question there is a button at the top to upload an image.

Comment: @joan: updated images

Comment: I can't make out which pins you are using for SDA, SCL, and ground.  What number pin are you using?  See http://pi.gadgetoid.com/pinout

Comment: @Joan: i have updated images.
Raspberry's 3 pin is connected IC;s first pin.  Purple colour
Raspberry's 5 pin is connected IC;s second pin.  yellow colour
Raspberry's 9 pin is connected IC;s fourth pin.  grey colour
Raspberry's 2 pin is connected IC;s 5,6,7,8 pin.  RED colour

Comment: Okay, that looks fine (the angle makes the pins a little hard to make out).  Try powering the DS1621 from 3V3 rather than 5V.  Some devices get confused if the I2C levels are different to the power levels.  Try moving the orange wire from Pi pin 2 (5V) to Pi pin 17 (3V3).

Comment: @Joan: Earlier i was using pin 1 which is also 3.3 volts. When it didnt worked i used pin 2 i.e. 5v. 

Do you think any problem with pi board?

Comment: Pretty unlikely.  Here is an alternative connection mode.  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KTYqgAQCRd4/UhR3oma8mqI/AAAAAAAAHnM/nqE2J6ENd7k/s400/RPi+with+DS1621.jpg A loose wire is the most likely problem.  If you can't get it to work try wiringPi's pintest utility or my [gpiotest](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) program.

Comment: @joan: Thanks a lot. It worked. Connecting A0,A1,A2 to gnd resulted into detection of my device as well as i am able to read temperature.

Really appreciated your help.

Comment: How odd.  It'll probably still work if you put them back to 3V3 now.  Perhaps it was a loose wire.

Comment: Sure. I am gonna try that out.